# How to create multiple email form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email

> I want to create a form which send message on  multiple email address 
>   can this possible using WordPress?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Comment: I don't see why not. Start coding!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. Use `wp_mail` function. here is refference  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

just remember there is a search engin called Google.You can easily find these kind of things from Google.You just need to type and hit enter.

Thank you